# Get ALL Google Fonts as Woff

Tags: html, css, fonts

Due to some concerns with GDPR I want to host all the google fonts myself

For background, I am building a text editor in which the user can pick any google font. The chosen font is then loaded on the fly.

This is not a problem, I downloaded them all from the official Git repository. However, in the zip they only give you ttf files not woff. I have read for max compatibility/performance woff is the preferred choice.

I have found sites like [this](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) that let you get individual fonts as woff but I want them all.

1. Does it really matter if I just use the ttf ? I can load them dynamically using [font face api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace) but is that OK cross browser?
2. If answer to 1 is that I should use woff (or something else), then how can I get the entire Google Fonts library as woff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to support IE, it's well supported across all other modern browsers.

[TTF/OTF - TrueType and OpenType font support](https://caniuse.com/ttf)

Answer (score 0):

You can download individual fonts as woff2 in this Google fonts repository. Here I'm pointing to DM Sans for an example.

https://github.com/googlefonts/dm-fonts/tree/main/Sans/fonts/webfonts